# gimp script-fu: drawing a simple line

Tags: scheme, drawing, gimp, script-fu

I'm trying to draw a line using gimp scripting. In the following script: I create a new image 512x512 and a I try to draw a diagonal (0,0)->(512,512).
But the image (tmp.xcf) remains transparent.

What am i doing wrong ?

```
(define (drawdiagonal W H)
(let* (
      (img 0)
       (bg 0)
       (points (cons-array 4 'double) )
      )
(set! img (car (gimp-image-new  W H 0)))
(gimp-image-undo-group-start img)
(gimp-context-push)
(set! bg (car (gimp-layer-new img  W H RGBA-IMAGE "background" 100 NORMAL-MODE)))
(gimp-image-add-layer img bg 0)
(gimp-drawable-set-visible bg TRUE)
(gimp-image-set-active-layer img bg)
(gimp-context-set-brush-size 10.0)
(gimp-context-set-opacity 100)
(gimp-context-set-paint-mode NORMAL-MODE)
(gimp-context-set-foreground '(255 127 0))
(gimp-selection-all img)

(aset points 0 0)
(aset points 1 0)
(aset points 2 W)
(aset points 3 H)
(gimp-paintbrush-default  bg 4 points)

(gimp-context-pop)
(gimp-image-undo-group-end img)

(gimp-xcf-save 1 img img "tmp.xcf"  "tmp.xcf")
(display "DONE")
)
)

(drawdiagonal 512 512) (gimp-quit 0)
```

usage:

```
cat test.scm | gimp -i  -b -
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are mostly missing:

```
(gimp-context-set-brush "Some brush")
```

Additionally, the 3rd argument there (2nd `img`) should be a drawable:

```
(gimp-xcf-save 1 img img "tmp.xcf"  "tmp.xcf")
```

PS: do yourself a favor and write your script in Python. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44430081/how-to-run-python-scripts-using-gimpfu-from-windows-command-line/44435560#44435560) for an example.

Edit post-Gimp 2.10: there is now an API to stroke paths in "Line" mode which is the best way to obtain clean results. The relevant calls are:

```
pdb.gimp_context_set_stroke_method(STROKE_LINE)
pdb.gimp_context_set_line_cap_style(...)
pdb.gimp_context_set_line_join_style(...)
pdb.gimp_context_set_line_miter_limit(...)
pdb.gimp_context_set_line_width(width)
pdb.gimp_drawable_edit_stroke_item(drawable, path)
```

Comment: very useful thanks ! (btw using gimp is a pretext to learn functional programming/scheme)

Comment: Some of my Python scripts contain a lot more functional programming than the sum of all the Scheme Gimp scripts I have seen. Scriptfu's are mostly procedural things written with a functional programming language.

Answer (score 1):

For those who may come along later, based on xenoid's hints, I made this using gimp-pencil.

[I found no documentation for the 'item/path' of gimp_drawable_edit_stroke_item]

Could be tweaked to use gimp-brush...

```
(define (util-draw-path drawable args . path)
  ;; Draw a zig-zag line:
  ;; (util-draw-path layer `((width 10) (color ,RED)) 10 50 40 80 70 30 110 90 150 80)
  (let ((save  (util-assq 'save args) #t)
        (color (util-assq 'color args))   ; else use context value
        (width (util-assq 'width args))   ; else use context value
        (miter (util-assq 'miter args))   ; else use context value
        (join  (util-assq 'join args))    ; else use context value
        (cap   (util-assq 'cap args))     ; else use context value
        (stroke (util-assq 'stroke args)) ; else use context value
        )
    (and save (gimp-context-push))
    (and miter (gimp-context-set-line-miter-limit miter)) ; default: 10, default mitre up to 60 pixels
    (and stroke (gimp-context-set-stroke-method stroke))  ; default STROKE-PAINT-METHOD
    (and cap (gimp-context-set-line-cap-style cap))       ; CAP-ROUND, CAP-SQUARE
    (and join (gimp-context-set-line-join-style join))    ; JOIN-MITER, JOIN-ROUND, JOIN-BEVEL
    (and color (gimp-context-set-foreground color))       ;
    (and width (gimp-context-set-line-width width))       ; default: 6

    (let ((vec (apply vector path)))
      (gimp-pencil drawable (vector-length vec) vec))
    (and save (gimp-context-pop))
    ))

;;; (util-assq key list [default]) -> value or [default or #f]
(macro (util-assq form)
  (let ((key (cadr form)) (lis (caddr form))
        (els (if (pair? (cdddr form)) (cadddr form) #f)))
    `(let ((v (assq ,key ,lis)))
       (if v (cadr v) ,els))))
```