# Script not using defined path

Tags: gimp, script-fu

Sorry for any errors, english is not my native language

I'm in need of a certain script to manipulate a bunch of images, to not bother people to death by asking "can someone do this for me?", i'm trying to learn how to write them myself.

I start by creating a script that will move images from one folder to another, from **/Images/origin** to **/Images/destination**, I need this to be a relative path since i need it to work anywhere as long as theres a origin and destination folder inside a Images folder.

Currently I have the next script (taken from what i could learn, copy and understand) but when saving an image it doesn't save where i expect it to go, actualy it does nothing.

```
(define (batch-move)  
   (let* (filelist (cadr (file-glob "/Image/origin/*.png" 1))))  
   (while (not (null? filelist)) 
      (let* ((filename (car filelist))  
      (image (car (gimp-file-load RUN-NONINTERACTIOVE filename filename)))  
      (draw (car (gimp-image-get-active-layer image)))  
      (gimp-file-save RUN-NONINTERACTIVE image draw filename/../destination filename)  
   (set! filelist (cdr filelist))
))))
```

The place where is the function(?) gimp-file-save, i've tried to put the path before, and in this example after, but it doesn't work.

This is assuming the filename is the complete path using /../ to go back a folder and /destination/ go to the next, same way as to navigate windows using relative path directories

I also understand that the gimp-image-get-active-layer is probably not necessary but this is for me to later add all the functions that i need.

And my question is why is it not working?, from what I gather the filename variable is the entire path, but if it isn't then what is is?

Comment: If you need to manipulate a bunch of images, GIMP is not the best choice. Better use some imaging library like PIL (for python) or others depending on you preferred programming language. Il will be faster.

Comment: I'm trying GIMP because it already has the functions i need to implement, and already played around with the values that i find give the best result. In python, from what i can find, i would need to implement several functions to achive the same results, but yeah if i can't get this to work i'll try using python instead.

Comment: Most of the trivial stuff (scale, crop, rotate, add annotations) are more easily handled with [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) which is really designed to be used from the command line or in shell scripts. For a sample Gimp python script called from the command line, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44430081/how-to-run-python-scripts-using-gimpfu-from-windows-command-line/44435560#44435560).