# Instead of giving command for batch mode, give .scm file path?

Tags: scheme, gimp

It is possible to supply batch commands directly with the -b flag, but if the commands become very long, this is no longer an option. Is there a way to give the path to an .scm script that was written to a file, without having to move the file into the scripts directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No as far as I know. What you give in the `-b` flag is a Scheme statement, which implies your function has already been loaded by the script executor process.  You can of course add more directories that are searched for scripts using `Edit>Preferences>Folders>Scripts`.

If you write your script in Python the problem is a bit different since you can [alter the Python path before loading the script code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44435560/6378557) but the command line remains a bit long.

Comment: Okay, I added a file exporter to my scm generator https://github.com/void4/PyGimpBatchGen/blob/master/gimpscm.py#L104 After the file is written to the scripts directory, I execute the script like a normal batch file by using the defined function name.