# Can I make a terminal program in C to edit photos in GIMP [macOS]?

Tags: c, terminal, gimp

I am editing a large batch of photos using the same steps, and want to create a program to run through terminal that will run the process for me. I am comfortable with writing in C, but I am unsure of how to start on the code/what commands to use.

When I am in GIMP, I start by opening a .xcf file, and importing the photo I wish to edit in as the bottom layer. Next, I resize the layer to 1000px wide. After that, I edit the curves with a preset I have saved, and then do the same with the brightness controls. Finally, I export the file as a .png with a specific name: 01-0xx.png, based on the number of the photo in the set.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a job for macros or the automation tools available in Gimp:

Ref: Gimp Automate Editing  https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Automate_Editing_in_GIMP/

> This tutorial will describe and provide examples for two types of
>   automation functions. The first function is a tool to capture and
>   execute “Macro” commands. The second function is a set of Automation
>   Tools to capture and run a “Flow” or “Process”. The code for this
>   tutorial is written using Gimp-Python and should be platform portable
>   – able to run on either Linux or Windows operating systems. *
>
> The goal of these functions is to provide tools that speed up the
>   editing process, make the editing process more repeatable, and reduce
>   the amount of button pushing the user has to do. Taking over the
>   button pushing and book-keeping chores allows the user to focus on the
>   more creative part of the editing process.

I haven't ever used GIMP, but programs of this sort typically have automation scripting support, and this is the right place to start.

Comment: The tutorial you point to is terrible, and way too complicated for a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Could be done with C, but the learning curve is steep.

You can write Gimp scripts in Scheme (Lisp) or Python, and if you know C you can learn enough Python in a couple of hours. See an example of a Python batch script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44430081/how-to-run-python-scripts-using-gimpfu-from-windows-command-line/44435560#44435560).

**Side note #1:** Curves+Brightness contrast can be done in one single call to Curves (with a different curve of course). Each operation entails some color loss, so the fewer, the better.

**Side note #2:** It may be simpler to do this with without Gimp using:

- The ImageMagick tool box (command called from a shell script)
- An image library with any language ("pillow" for python).

Your `Curves` preset is just what is called a "CLUT" (Color Look-Up Table).