# How to run a batch file to run a python-fu gimp script?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, gimp, python-fu

Further to the question here about [how to run python scripts using gimpfu from windows command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44430081/how-to-run-python-scripts-using-gimpfu-from-windows-command-line/44435560#44435560), is there a way to neatly package up the script? That's to say, without having to type a long (and complicated command line) - it's not for me it; I need to make this as easy as possible for a third party to deploy. The two unknowns being the path of Gimp and the location of the folder where the script processes the images.

Ideally this would be in a batch file that the user can run from the directory that the file is in. I need them both in PC and Mac flavours.

I'm new to gimp and am unsure of my options at this moment in time.

Comment: A batch script of course. Not complicated even on windows. What did you try?

Comment: `batch file` is mentioned in title, link and body of your post. In the link, batch file is used to describe a Python script. You use a `batch-file` tag which is a script run by command.com or cmd.exe in Windows. Perhaps, the `python` tag is intended instead of the `batch-file` tag. Python can run on Windows and Mac, of which you state a need.