# Gimp automation(Scripz Fu/Python Fu)

Tags: python, scheme, gimp, script-fu, python-fu

I have a design and need to download them in batch  but every download has another variable. For instance the design is:

I like [variable]

variable should be different at any download.
Example of variables: [Programming, Basketball, food]

So download one is : I like Programming.
Download two: I like Basketball.
Download three: I like food.

Does somebody know how to do that? I get confused with Python Fu or Script Fu

[image: example]

Comment: What you want to do isn't clear at all. Why is Gimp involved if you want to download things? Or are you trying to create images with variable text? Python-fu is more powerful (and for many people easier to master) than script-fu (which is a Lisp/Scheme dialect).

Comment: @xenoid because when you create an image, I need to download it, otherwise it would be useless...I added a picture to the post. Hope it makes things clearer

Comment: What you do with the image is not Gimp's concern... So yes, what you want is an image with variable text, which means you have to script inserting the text and transforming it. If you are using the text without any effect applied (or with very simple effects), using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/) would be simpler and more efficient.

Comment: If you are applying effects in Gimp, you have to write an equivalent script, and once you have that code you can put it in a [batch procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44430081/how-to-run-python-scripts-using-gimpfu-from-windows-command-line/44435560#44435560)