# Can't run Gimp batch commands from a Mac / OSX

Tags: python, macos, gimp, python-fu

I'm trying to have Gimp batch process some files in OSX. The best example I've found is in this post: [How to run python scripts using gimpfu from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44430081/how-to-run-python-scripts-using-gimpfu-from-command-line). However for launching Gimp in batch mode, this, and every other example starts looks like this:

*gimp -idf --batch-interpreter python-fu-eval -b "import sys;sys.path=['.']+sys.path;import batch;batch.run('./images')" -b "pdb.gimp_quit(1)*

I can't just type "gimp" at my OSX command line though. I have to type "open /Applications/GIMP-2.10.app" and then including the various command line arguments throws up errors related to the "open" command.

I tried making an alias in my bash profile so that typing "gimp" launches "open /Applications/GIMP-2.10.app" but I'm still getting open errors.

Is there something else I need to do in OSX to just be able to type "gimp" and launch with command line args?

Comment: What sort of commands/processing do you want to run? IMHO, it may potentially be far simpler just to use built-in `sips` or **ImageMagick**.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your alias `/Applications/GIMP-2.10.app/Contents/MacOS/gimp`.  That's where the traditional executables live.  Or, make a symbolic link in `/usr/local/bin`.

Answer (score 1):

For the dummies like me: You can add the alias to the  ~/.alias file. Add the line:

alias mygimpname "/Applications/Gimp-2.10.app/Contents/MacOS/gimp"

Save the file
Then type this in the terminal:

source ~/.alias

If you put a symbolic link in the bin directory, when you run gimp it fails with errors that the babl installation is broken. And then you need a workaround for that...
Just use the alias.

Comment: getting `source: command not found`

Comment: (1) The path needs to be updated to the current GIMP app. In my case that's "/Applications/Gimp-2.10.34.app/Contents/MacOS/gimp"
 . 
(2) Also, the syntax of the "alias" command that I needed was "alias gimpcmd="/Applications/..." with an "=" instead of a space.

Answer (score 0):

Tim Roberts's suggestion of making my alias /Applications/GIMP-2.10.app/Contents/MacOS/gimp worked. Although I later learned shell scripts don't use system aliases, I at least have a command line alias, and can call the full path from a shell script.

Thank you!