# Imagemagick: Are there any operators that could convert all spots on b/w mages into pixel placed at geometric center?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, image-manipulation, imagemagick-convert

I have a huge set of black and white images with spots and want to replace every spot into pixel (or small circle) that is located in the geometric center of the spot.

[image]

Because the spots has different sizes, I could not consequently use dilate operator because it completely deletes small sports. Is there any way to do this automatical with Imagemagick?

Comment: You can use -connected-components to fine the centroids of each region and the bounding boxes. Use the bounding box to approximate the diameter of the circle or draw the same size circles for each spot.  Use -draw to draw the circles.  But be careful, it will mess with your arc on the right side unless you threshold to filter it out on the bounding box sizes.

Comment: Completely different way: Using Gimp, create a color selection on black, convert the selection to a path (so you get a collection of tiny polygons), and compute the centroid of these. If needed, create a new layer and paint the pixel at these coordinates (but maybe you just want the coordinate, in which case you can write it to a file directly). Of course if you have a convex spot the centroid can be outside...

Comment: @xenoid, I have some thousands files and need a script that does all work automatically.

Comment: @fmw42, can you write a script example?

Comment: @IvanZ you can script Gimp and make it execute things in batch. What you want to do is less than 20 lines of Python code. The rest is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44430081/how-to-run-python-scripts-using-gimpfu-from-windows-command-line/44435560#44435560).

Comment: Kindly state your operating system. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kudos (and upvotes) to Fred (@fmw42) for the original technique. As much for my own curiosity as anything (and to document the approach), I wanted to make a variant that is hopefully more CPU-friendly, I/O friendly and maybe more portable. This should also have advantages given that OP has large numbers of images to process.

I worked on the following aspects:

- rather than repeatedly load the image, draw a circle and re-save for every circle, I wanted to use a script that loads it once, draws all the circles and saves it
- reduce dependency on other tools, and their process creation times - so all the `cut`, `grep`, `tr`, `convert`, `echo` and so on are encapsulated inside a single, `awk` invocation leveraging its built-in ability to split fields, process text, and do math. Hopefully this makes it easier to port to Windows too as fewer binaries are needed.

So, it looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

magick black_spots.png \
   -threshold 50% -type bilevel \
   -define connected-components:mean-color=true \
   -define connected-components:area-threshold=0-300 \
   -define connected-components:verbose=true \
   -connected-components 8 null: | awk -F'[ x+]*' '
      BEGIN       { print "black_spots.png -fill white -colorize 100 -fill black" }
      /gray\(0\)/ {
                    w=$3; h=$4; x=$5; y=$6; cx=x+w/2; cy=y+h/2
                    printf("-draw \"translate %f,%f circle 0,0 0,5\"\n", cx, cy)
                  }
      END         { print "-write result.png"}
   ' | magick -script -
```

[image]

---

The `awk` part in the middle actually generates a script that looks like this:

```
black_spots.png -fill white -colorize 100 -fill black
-draw "translate 1429.000000,368.000000 circle 0,0 0,5"
-draw "translate 6.000000,1026.500000 circle 0,0 0,5"
-draw "translate 739.500000,378.000000 circle 0,0 0,5"
...
...
-write result.png
```

That is then piped into `magick -script` at the end. Hopefully it is clear that the input file is only read once, all the circles are drawn, then the output file is written - just once.

---

Some notes on the `awk` parts:

- `-F'[ x+]*'` means that multiple spaces, the letter `x` and `+` signs should all be treated as field separators
- `BEGIN` and `END` blocks are executed once at the start and end of the `awk` script
- the `/gray\(0\)/` block is executed only on lines containing `gray(0)`

---

As regards processing large numbers of files, I would use **GNU Parallel**, but you have not indicated your operating system. Basically, modify the above script to accept a filename as a parameter, save it as `ProcessOne`, make it executable with `chmod +x ProcessOne`, then run:

```
parallel ./ProcessOne ::: *.png
```

and it will keep all your CPU cores busy processing all your files in parallel till they are all done. You can get progress bars and ETAs with various switches:

```
parallel --eta ...         # show ETA
parallel --progress ...    # report progress
parallel --bar ...         # add progress bar
parallel -j 4 ...          # just run 4 jobs in parallel
```

Comment: Nice solution. But I'm working in Windows. Does this script can work in it?

Comment: It should be possible to make it work under Windows. First, you would need to install **ImageMagick**, then you'd need to install `gawk`, If you can do that, and let me know when you have done it, we can work out together how to adapt to Windows.

Comment: Alternatively, it should be possible to do it using Python with **OpenCV** installed if that is easier for you. It could use multiprocessing internally too in order to speed things up for large numbers of files.

Comment: I try to use **ImageMagick** with `awk`.

Comment: Mark, it looks like you are drawing at the center of the bounding boxes and not the centroids of the regions. Is that correct? From Wikipedia: "In mathematics and physics, the centroid is also known as geometric center". Connected components reports the centroid in addition to the bounding box. So you could extract that directly rather than compute the centers of the bounding boxes.

Comment: Mark, I am not an AWK expert. But you have a line `      /gray\(0\)/ {` that looks to me out of place that likely was a copy and paste error from my grep "gray(0)".  If not a typo, please explain further.

Comment: @fmw42 Yes, that's what my comment was referring to below your answer. OP asked for *"geometric centre"* which I interpreted as being the centre of the rectangle containing the blob. If I wanted the centre as calculated by weighted distances (moments) I would pretty much always say *"centroid"*. Maybe OP will clarify - it's an easy alteration, if necesary. Thank you for checking.

Comment: That is a regex that means the following block enclosed within `{...}` is only executed on lines containg `gray(0)`. The braces are escaped though by preceding with backslashes and the whole thing is enclosed in `/.../` which is how `awk` likes it.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know you could do that.

Comment: So `awk '/mark/ {print $0}' file` is equivalent to `grep mark file` And you can have multiple, different patterns `awk '/mark/{print "good"} /fred/{print "also good"}' file`

Comment: @fmw42 I'm not disagreeing or trying to argue, but my (maybe English) interpretation was like this https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Geometric-center-vs-centroid_fig3_280841445

Comment: Interesting. I was going by Wikipedia and my interpretation of geometric center. My Google search found Wikipedia as the first thing. We will have to see what the OP actually wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to use -connected-components in Imagemagick to put circles where the spots are located.

This is a Unix Bash script using Imagemagick.

1. Save the internal file separator
2. Set the internal file separator to a new line rather than a space
3. Create an array holding the dat and read the input
4. Make a copy of the input and write over it with white and save
5. Threshold the input and save a bilevel
6. Set the output of connected components to the mean-color of the regions
7. Threshold the regions to those that between 0 and 300 pixels in area (This will discard your long arc on the right for the most part. It may throw out large spots. So change as desired)
   8) Set the connected components to verbose output to get the textual data
8. Set the connected components type to 8 connected rather than 4 connected
9. Save only black regions and filter to get only the second and third fields which are the bounding box and the centroid
10. Get the number of lines of data (one line per region)
11. Print to the terminal the number of lines of data
12. Start a For loop over each line of data
13. Get the bounding box width
14. Get the bounding box height
15. Compute the radius from the bounding box width and height
16. Get the centroid
17. Print to the terminal the line number, width, height, radius and centroid
18. Draw a black circle on the white image for each line of data, i.e. using the centroid and radius
19. end the loop
20. Set the internal file separator back to the save space separator

Input:

[image]

```
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
dataArr=(`convert black_spots.png \
\( +clone -fill white -colorize 100 -write black_spots_result.png +delete \) \
-threshold 50% -type bilevel \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-define connected-components:area-threshold=0-300 \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-connected-components 8 null: |\
grep "gray(0)" | awk '{print $2, $3}' | tr "x" "+"`)
num=${#dataArr[*]}
echo $num
for ((i=0; i<num; i++)); do
ww=`echo ${dataArr[$i]} | cut -d\  -f1 | cut -d+ -f1`
hh=`echo ${dataArr[$i]} | cut -d\  -f1 | cut -d+ -f2`
rad=`convert xc: -format "%[fx:($ww+$hh)/4]" info:`
cent=`echo ${dataArr[$i]} | cut -d\  -f2`
echo "$i $ww $hh $rad $cent"
convert black_spots_result.png -fill black -draw "translate $cent circle 0,0 0,$rad" black_spots_result.png
done
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Nice solution - you already have my vote. It probably doesn't matter for small shapes (and you do indeed have a threshold of 300px) but technically the replacement circle is placed at the centroid rather than at the geometric centre as OP asked.

Comment: Mark, it is the centroid as reported in -connected-components.