# How do you use ImageMagick script files?

Tags: command-line, imagemagick

I'm currently trying to create an image with a very large number of other images using ImageMagick. Each image has its own crop values, and placement within the larger image. Rather than a large number of read/writes to the output image, I'd like to send the command all at once, but it is far too large to pass via the command line.

I've found references to a seemingly undocumented feature of ImageMagick, scripts. However I can't seem to figure them out. Take this very simple command from the docs:

`magick -size 50x50 xc:skyblue an_image.png -composite output.png`

This creates a blue square, "pastes" `an_image.png` onto it, and saves it as `output.png`. However I'm struggling to recreate even this with a script:

**script.mgk:**

```
-size 50x50 xc:skyblue an_image.png -composite output.png
```

**command:**

```
magick -script script.mgk
```

The above outputs the error:

*magick: unable to open image 'output.png': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3569.*

Trying additional lines yields similar errors. Though if `an_image.png` doesn't exist (for example) it will instead print an error saying that that file couldn't be found.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scripting feature is documented [here](https://imagemagick.org/script/magick-script.php).

There are a few examples on StackOverflow too, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75967756/2836621) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75812376/2836621) and others.

Specifically, on the command line, the last item is assumed to be a filename and the results get written there. When using the script interface, however, there is no such assumption, and you need `-write filename` if you want a file created. You should be able to see that in the cited examples hopefully.

So, in concrete terms, change your script to:

```
-size 50x50 xc:skyblue
an_image.png -composite
-write output.png
```

Comment: This is fantastic, thanks very much! (And thanks even more for ImageMagick itself!) For my own curiousity, adding an image entry like: `an_image.png -crop 20x20+10+5 -composite`
Causes an error, and adding the -crop before the file name crops the output image. I realised it's better to do this instead: `an_image.png[20x20+10+5] -composite`. But I was wondering what the correct syntax would be for the former, to try and understand ImageMagick itself a bit better, haha.

Comment: It's generally a good idea to add `+repage` immediately after cropping, trimming, resizing so maybe see if that does the trick. Version 7 of **ImageMagick** is miles more powerful and expressive than v6 and as a result it is more picky about the order of its parameters - for example you can't use `-crop` before loading an image like you used to be able to.